# highlight cell with same value in different sheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016

Excel 2016.
I have two cell ranges in two different sheets: sheet1!B2:B250, and sheet2!B2:B164 for customers names.

When I insert a cell in between the cell range in any sheet and type a name e.g. "George", I want that cell highlighted if "George" already exists in those ranges. Please note that there are empty cells in both ranges that I don't want highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNTIF` function to create Conditional Formatting to format cells, please follow my steps and check if it will help you.

For **Sheet1!B2:B250** please use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B$2:$B$164,B2)>0
```

Select the range **Sheet1!B2:B250** and go to **Home**->> **Conditional Formatting**->> **NEw Rule**...->> Please select **Use a Formula to determine which cells to format**->> type the formula->> **Format** cells.

[image]

For **Sheet2!B2:B164** please use this formula:

```
=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$250,B2)>0
```

The same steps as Sheet1:

[image]

Comment: It only works for the existing cells in those ranges. As I've said I want to **insert** a new cell in any of the ranges and type there a name.